# Set Timezone in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datetime-format

I need date in IST timezone. By default, server returns Date in timezone UTC.

Changed the TimeZone by adding this code:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```

This works for me except when user set datetime explicitly since in that case user specified time is already in IST.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-time-string", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object getTime(
            @RequestParam(value = "user_specified_time", required=false) @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") Date date
    ){
        return date.toString();
    }
```

How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: ideally, you should use UTC everywhere including the client sending the request

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich why so?

Comment: @Gautam Kumar otherwise you will end up with such implications having troubles converting date everywhere. In your particular case you can convert date on client in JS code. Dates are saved in database in UTC usually as well in order not mess with it all the time

Comment: Don’t rely on a three letter time zone abbreviation. `TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")` will give you Israel Standard Time on one server, India Standard Time on another and who knows, maybe Irish Summer Time on a third. Use for example `Asia/Jerusalem` or `Europe/Dublin` to avoid the ambiguity.